# Python: Passing variables into Wordnet Synsets methods in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I need to work on a project that require NLTK so I started learning Python two weeks ago but struggling to understand Python and NLTK.

From the NLTK documentation, I can understand the following codes and they work well if I manually add the word apple and pear into the codes below.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

apple = wn.synset('apple.n.01')
pear = wn.synset('pear.n.01')

print apple.lch_similarity(pear)

Output: 2.53897387106
```

However, I need to use the NLTK to work with a list of items. For example, I have a list of items below and I would like to compare the items from list1 with list2 - for example: compare word1 from list1 with every word in list 2, then word2 from list1 with every word from list2 until all words in list1 is compared.

```
list1 = ["apple", "honey", "drinks", "flowers", "paper"]
list2 = ["pear", "shell", "movie", "fire", "tree", "candle"]

wordFromList1 = list1[0]
wordFromList2 = list2[0]

wordFromList1 = wn.synset(wordFromList1)
wordFromList2 = wn.synset(wordFromList2)    

print wordFromList1.lch_similarity(wordFromList2)
```

The codes above will of course gives an error. Can anyone show me how I can pass a *variable* into synset method [wn.synset(*pass_variable_in_here*)] so that I can use a double loop to get the lch_similarity values for them. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wordnet.synset` expects a [3-part
name](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html) string of the form:
`word.pos.nn`.

You did not specify the `pos.nn` part for each word in `list1` and
`list2`.

It seems reasonable to assume that all the words are nouns, so we could try
appending the string `'.n.01'` to each string in `list1` and `list2`:

```
for word1, word2 in IT.product(list1, list2):
    wordFromList1 = wordnet.synset(word1+'.n.01')
    wordFromList2 = wordnet.synset(word2+'.n.02')
```

That does not work, however. `wordnet.synset('drinks.n.01')` raises a `WordNetError`.

On the other hand, the [same doc
page](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html) shows you can
lookup similar words using the `synsets` method:

For example, `wordnet.synsets('drinks')` returns the list:

```
[Synset('drink.n.01'),
 Synset('drink.n.02'),
 Synset('beverage.n.01'),
 Synset('drink.n.04'),
 Synset('swallow.n.02'),
 Synset('drink.v.01'),
 Synset('drink.v.02'),
 Synset('toast.v.02'),
 Synset('drink_in.v.01'),
 Synset('drink.v.05')]
```

So at this point, you need to give some thought to what you want the program to do. If you are okay with just picking the first item in this list as a proxy for `drinks`,
then you could use

```
for word1, word2 in IT.product(list1, list2):
    wordFromList1 = wordnet.synsets(word1)[0]
    wordFromList2 = wordnet.synsets(word2)[0]
```

which would result in a program that looks like this:

```
import nltk.corpus as corpus
import itertools as IT

wordnet = corpus.wordnet
list1 = ["apple", "honey", "drinks", "flowers", "paper"]
list2 = ["pear", "shell", "movie", "fire", "tree", "candle"]

for word1, word2 in IT.product(list1, list2):
    # print(word1, word2)
    wordFromList1 = wordnet.synsets(word1)[0]
    wordFromList2 = wordnet.synsets(word2)[0]
    print('{w1}, {w2}: {s}'.format(
        w1 = wordFromList1.name,
        w2 = wordFromList2.name,
        s = wordFromList1.lch_similarity(wordFromList2)))
```

which yields

```
apple.n.01, pear.n.01: 2.53897387106
apple.n.01, shell.n.01: 1.07263680226
apple.n.01, movie.n.01: 1.15267950994
apple.n.01, fire.n.01: 1.07263680226
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! I've only learned the basic Python and I don't know how I can pass a variable into the method call. Before posting this question, I tried the [+ ".n.01] method but it gave me an error.  Why did wordnet.synsets(word1)[0] works instead?

Comment: Always keep in mind that (just about) everything in Python is an object. `wordnet.synsets(word1)` is a `list`. A `list` is an object which can be indexed: `list[0]` returns the first item in the `list`. So `wordnet.synsets(word1)[0]` returns an object such as `Synset('drink.n.01')`, which is the same kind of object as `wordnet.synset('drink.n.01')`. It is a so-called "instance" of the class `Synset`. So instead of defining `wordFormList1 = wordnet.synset(...)` directly, which encountered problems, we were able to proceed by obtaining a `Synset` instance by an alternative route.